# Is Jpedal Library Free?

Tags: java, pdf, jpedal

Is Jpedal library totally free?
As I noticed the download link is mentioning trial! :(

Comment: Do you need a free/open source alternative?

Comment: Downloads page also links to LGPL viewer

Comment: @ Boris Pavlović  Yes I do need a free full java library to render PDF files.

Comment: @ Boris Pavlović I need the library not the Viewer!

Comment: There is PDFRenderer, Icepdf or Mulitvalent.

Comment: they say that PDFRenderer does not support all new features of PDF files and I could not download it anywhere! :( Where can I find it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Full JPedal library is proprietary/commercial licensed: http://www.jpedal.org/support_faq.php#licensing

A cut-down version is open source under LGPL.

Comment: That link redirects to the companies home page. The pricing for the licence is at the bottom of this page: https://www.idrsolutions.com/jpedal/

Answer (score 2):

You need to do more research.

A quick search of the website shows that the pdf viewer is LGPL, while the full client is not.
See [JPedal Download the 30 day trial version](http://www.jpedal.org/open_source_pdf_viewer_download.php) and [JPedal - Commercial vs LGPL version comparison](http://www.jpedal.org/open_source_pdf_viewer_download.php)

Answer (score 2):

Yes Jpedal is totally free if you comply to the LGPL license.

**Update**:

The world changed in the meantime and the (LGPL) open source Jpedal was stopped. If you look for that version it was removed from [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jpedal). The last vrsion was based on the 4.92 Version you can download it [here](https://github.com/Lonzak/JPedal). This library is using Swing/AWT for rendering PDFs.

A while ago the newer version of Jpedal was released under the name of '[OpenViewerFX](https://github.com/IDRSolutions/maven-OpenViewerFX-src)' and is basically the same as above but using JavaFX for rendering PDFs. Since JavaFX is used it needs Java 1.8.

**Update II**:

The OpenViewerFX was also discontinued. So there is currently no open source version of jpedal. You can still find the code [here](https://github.com/Lonzak/OpenViewerFX).

Answer (score 0):

There's a section in their FAQ that covers the licensing issue: [Jpedal FAQ](http://www.jpedal.org/support_faq.php#licensing)

Answer (score 0):

For those searching for the free version, you can get *JPedal LGPL v4.92b23* here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jpedal.jpedal-lgpl/jpedal-lgpl/4.92b23

There's also a github fork [here](https://github.com/Lonzak/JPedal). Testing it for pdf->png conversion seemed to produce mixed results compared to the original version.